# COUNTIFS with double match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using this formula: **COUNTIFS($B$2:$AF$2;"Sat";B4:AF4;"r")**
to count all R values on "Sat"
but I need to count all R values that are in Sat and next cell simultaneously (in my example G4 and H4)
how can I point the next cell[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just offset another range:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$AF$2;"Sat";B4:AF4;"r";C4:AG4;"r")
```

This will only return 1 given your setup, if you want to count both `r` then just multiply by 2:

```
 =COUNTIFS($B$2:$AF$2;"Sat";B4:AF4;"r";C4:AG4;"r") * 2
```

It will count 1 for each combo then multiply by two to count the number of `r` that match the pattern.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's not working if the the Sat value is at the begining

Comment: @NikosKioses edit your own post to include clarifications, do not edit my post to do so.